# Analytically estimate occurances of motif in random network

Tags: graph, graph-theory

I am looking for a way to compute the estimated occurrence of a given motif/subgraph in a random network. For example, I am given a network motif `M`, which has three vertices and three edges: `(A->B, B->C, C->A)`. What is the expected occurrence of `M` in a random network with `n` vertices and `k` edges?

I know methods that generate a random graph and then enumerate `M`. Since that is computationally expensive, I wondered if there are more straightforward methods to compute the estimated occurrences.

Comment: It is not exactly clear how the random network is generated and what is allowed (bi-directed edges, multiple edges, etc.), although the latter shouldn't make a substantial difference. Is it a variant of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model with fixed number of edges for directed graphs or something else?

Comment: At any rate, if you are looking for the expected number of occurrences of a given subgraph, computing the precise values fast might be out of reach but should be possible to approximate reasonably well in models where you pick each edge to belong to your random graph with a certain probability.